# Changing the default lightdm greeter not working on Arch with XFCE

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, lightdm

I installed two greeters:

```
ls -la /usr/share/xgreeters
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  187 Sep  6  2022 lightdm-gtk-greeter.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  137 May 25 04:52 lightdm-mini-greeter.desktop
```

And made the change to select a greeter session in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:

```
greeter-session = lightdm-mini-greeter
```

I have the greeter config in /etc/lightdm/lightdm-mini-greeter.conf.

This is per instructions on https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LightDM and https://github.com/prikhi/lightdm-mini-greeter.

However, looking at the logs in /var/log/lightdm from when the system boots:

```
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG:   [LightDM] contains unknown option greeter-session
...
[+1.45s] DEBUG: Session pid=599: Running command /usr/bin/lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

I am then greeted by the default gtk greeter.

If you can share any idea what I may be doing wrong, or what else I should configure?

Comment: Try it without the spaces either side of the “=“ They are absent in the Arch wiki

Comment: Nope, no effect. Still gives the same log output.